# How do you keep track of machines, password, accounts etc?

Tags: password, password-management

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you manage your passwords?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21374/how-do-you-manage-your-passwords)
>   [How do you manage service account credentials (passwords) ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29660/how-do-you-manage-service-account-credentials-passwords)

I've long since passed the line where I can remember passwords and names of everything I need for daily operation.

That means everything from root passwords for *nix machines, IP addresses/hostnames, VPN connection credentials, database user/passwords and so on.

How do you organize and keep track of all that ?

Comment: -1 Duplicate: see http://serverfault.com/questions/10285/best-practise-and-solutions-for-sharing-passwords or http://serverfault.com/questions/21374/how-do-you-manage-your-passwords, and that's just two likely-looking results from putting "password" in the search box on the upper right.

Comment: I just ask Bruce Schneier-- he already knows all my passwords, and yours too.

Comment: @EvanAnderson I remember snickering at that comment the first time I noticed it, two years later I still laughed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I like KeePass myself.

Its free, can be installed/run on a USB stick and also has an interface for my Andriod phone.

http://keepass.info

Here's a link to some screenshots of the program:

http://keepass.info/screenshots.html#scr2x

Answer (score 1):

Another option for your password records is to write them down, keeping them secured in a safe.

This way they aren't accessible on your network. Granted the physical security may be a cause for concern, but so can storing your passwords on your work computer even with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Passkeeper](http://www.passkeeper.com/) for passwords and [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) for non-confidential information.  Passkeeper is a Windows application, but was portable (no installer required) before portable apps became common.  TiddlyWiki is a portable, cross-platform wiki in a self-contained HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Carl's setup we use [password safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/) for usernames/passwords, and [dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) for everything else. We picked dokuwiki cause it fairly lightweight and doesn't require a database. Because it's all textfile based it's very easy to generate independent redundant copies. When things go wrong you can never have too many copies of your documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be asking because you should have a solution in place long before you need to ask. Having said that, I use PasswordSafe for passwords, mainly because it is cross-platform. Most other information is stored in a MySQL database, with MS Access as the front on Windows machines.

The company I work for also requires me to provide updated hard copies of all system details and passwords. Those are stored in a fireproof safe at a remote location. They're kind of nervous since the entire building and contents were destroyed by fire about 8 years ago.