# What software do you use for storing application authorizations?

Tags: active-directory, authorization

We are a medium sized company with a Windows 2003 network, using Active Directory for our users (about 100) and computers (about 50). 
We also have a small number of applications that need their own authorization.

Now we need to regularly produce a report with all users and their authorizations (such as roles and membership).

Is there software where I can store this information, for example automatically from Active Directory and manually from the other applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the responses to my question at [How do you manage service account credentials (passwords)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29660/how-do-you-manage-service-account-credentials-passwords)